# How do I, in Groovy, compare a user date input with todays date and make decisions based on user input being before or after todays date?

Tags: groovy

I'm finding the date with the following script:

```js
import java.time.*

def today = LocalDateTime.now();
 
execution.setVariable("today", today);
```

Which is returning the following information 2017-06-22T18:07:09.958.

I need to take that date and compare it to a users input of say 12/12/12 and make decisions based off of whether the users date is before or after today.

Answer (score 0):

Simply parse the user input and compare it:

```
import java.time.*
import java.time.format.*

def today = LocalDate.now()
def userInput = "12/12/12"
def formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yy/MM/dd")
def userDate = LocalDate.parse(userInput, formatter)

println "$userDate is ${userDate.isAfter(today) ? 'after' : 'before'} today"
```

Prints:

```
2012-12-12 is before today
```

I couldn't figure out your desired date pattern from `12/12/12` so you might need to adjust that. You would also need to decide what to do with equal dates, currently "today" would be "before today", but you can handle that using `userDate == today`.